# Поменять стиль родительского элемента

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, необходимо при наведении на кнопку внутри блока поменять цвет родительского блока. А именно блока 'type'.

```css
.block.plan {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 50px 0 50px 0; }
  .block.plan .items .planBlock {
    width: -webkit-calc(100% - 40px);
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin: 0 auto 30px;
    text-align: center; }
    .block.plan .items .planBlock .type {
      padding: 10px 0;
      background: #485460; }
      .block.plan .items .planBlock .type h3 {
        font-size: 2rem;
        color: #ffffff; }
    .block.plan .items .planBlock .price {
      padding: 10px 0;
      background: #f8f9fb; }
      .block.plan .items .planBlock .price p {
        color: #6b757f;
        font-size: 1.5rem; }
    .block.plan .items .planBlock table {
      width: 100%;
      background: #ffffff; }
      .block.plan .items .planBlock table tbody {
        width: 100%; }
        .block.plan .items .planBlock table tbody tr {
          width: 100%; }
          .block.plan .items .planBlock table tbody tr td {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 10px 0;
            background: #ffffff;
            border: 1px solid #ecf0f1;
            color: #8c9299;
            font-size: 1.125rem; }
    .block.plan .items .planBlock .btnBlock {
      width: 100%;
      padding: 30px 40px;
      background: #f8f9fb; }
      .block.plan .items .planBlock .btnBlock a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #ffffff;
        font-weight: 600;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font-size: 1.5rem;
        background: #788492;
        padding: 10px 40px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                border-radius: 5px; }
      .block.plan .items .planBlock .btnBlock a:hover {
        background: #49cbcd; }
        .block.plan .items .planBlock .btnBlock a:hover .planblock .type {
          background: #49cbcd; }
```

```html
<section class = "block plan">
   <div class = "items">

    <div class = "planBlock basic">
     <div class = "type">
      <h3>Basic</h3>
     </div>
     <div class = "price">
      <p>$5.01/Month</p>
     </div>
     <table>
      <tr><td>Lorem ipsum</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Dolor sit amet, consect</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Adipiscing elit</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Proin commodo turpis</td></tr>
      <tr><td>lacus pulvinarvel </td></tr>
      <tr><td>Prnare nisi pretium.</td></tr>
     </table>
     <div class = "btnBlock">
      <a href = "#" class = "btnBuy">Buy now</a>
     </div>
    </div>
        </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выражайтесь правильно: это не родительский элемент, а сосед родительского элемента. Найти его можно при помощи `.parent()` - ищет родительский элемент и `.siblings()` - ищет соседний элемент.

```
$('.btnBuy').on('mouseover', function(){ //присвоить цвет при наведении мыши
  $(this).parent().siblings('.type').css({'background': '#49cbcd'});
});

$('.btnBuy').on('mouseleave', function(){ //убрать цвет при отведении мыши
  $(this).parent().siblings('.type').css({'background': ''});
});
```

Пример: https://jsfiddle.net/9Ldyxx6j/